# jQuery Textarea-Expander plugin (I need padding)

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

There is a **textarea expander jquery plugin** that has been mentioned a bit on stackoverflow: 
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html

This works great in all browser, BUT, there is no padding on top/bottom in the textarea, which makes it look kind of ugly. So the simple solution (I thought) was to comment out this line, or change the 0 to 10 for example:

`$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);`

It still works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome and Safari, it doesn't. For each character I type, the textarea expands until it reaches max height. The more padding I use, the more it expands

I was thinking maybe to compensate this only in webkit browsers, and remove the padding-top+bottom from the height that it sets, but I don't have a clue how.

I have tried some other plugins, but they didn't work very well either, so this seems to be the most stable one, except for the padding issues.

Did anyone suceed in making this look good?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gaequery/source/browse/trunk/src/static/scripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js) instead

There is an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHNW/3/) of it working with `padding`.

Comment: Thanks. The autogrow plugin didn't work for me, got a lot of \n\r in the entire textarea after saving. I ended up using [elastic](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/) which worked perfectly with padding :) However, I liked Textarea-expander that allowed me to type class=expand50-250 to get e height of 50, and a max-height of 250.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap code. here all are default css code. Its reduced your work.
Here you can set height and width, whatever you want.

html

```
 <textarea class='autogrow'></textarea>
```

css

```
textarea {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Demo: [demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwHNW/4/)